# Google maps API will not load grey box

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the first time I've used a google api and I followed the instructions exactly but the map won't load just the grey box that I started with, please help.

```
<div class="map">
</div> 
 <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>

function apimap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -73.993439, lng: 40.750545};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
```

Comment: The posted code will generate javascript errors and doesn't contain a `<div>` with id="map".  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a SO code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an issue regarding your implementation. You are using **apimap()** as your init function while in your **load request's callback**, you are using **initMap()**. You should replace initMap() with apimap() or vice-versa. With this, your map will work.

I've replicated your issue, the location is in **Antartica**. You can check the demo below.

```js
      var map;
      function apimap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -73.993439, lng: 40.750545};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: uluru,
          zoom: 4
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=apimap"
    async defer></script>
```

And also, please refrain from posting your Google Maps API key unless it is restricted to prevent abuse and to avoid your API key being used by unauthorized applications. To learn more about API restrictions, you can check **[Restricting an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#key-restrictions)**.

Hope it could help and good luck on your coding!